# Struts2, Tiles, "Response already committed" exception, and Flush interception

Tags: java, struts2, tiles

I get always the well known "Response already committed" due to a premature buffer flushing.

I want to discover where and when it happens.

Could anybody tell me about how to intercept where the flush occurs?

Comment: The question is clear "Could anybody tell me about how to intercept where the flush occurs?".

Comment: Ok, so clear will be the answer: no, not without seeing any code, configuration or whatever.

Comment: You could use byte-code manipulation to wrap the flush method and throw an exception. Buuuut it might just be easier to diagnose the issue via source, since it's almost always a trivial mistake or incorrect assumption about when things happen.